# 'React/RCTAppSetupUtils.h' file not found when integrating React Native with existing project

Tags: react-native, appdelegate

i got this problem when run app:
***/AppDelegate.mm:7:9: fatal error: 'React/RCTAppSetupUtils.h' file not found***

here is appDelegate.mm [pastebin link](https://pastebin.com/9zyJvSww)

when i run npm doctor is show everything ok:

```
Check                               Value  Recommendation/Notes
npm ping                            ok
npm -v                              ok     current: v8.6.0, latest: v8.6.0
node -v                             ok     current: v17.9.0, recommended: v17.9.0
npm config get registry             ok     using default registry (https://registry.npmjs.org/)
which git                           ok     /usr/bin/git
Perms check on cached files         ok
Perms check on local node_modules   ok
Perms check on global node_modules  ok
Perms check on local bin folder     ok
Perms check on global bin folder    ok
Verify cache contents               ok     verified 1913 tarballs
```

PLease help my problem

Comment: beware version of react native and podfile, please using rn upgrade helper to make it run normally